# Compare from Json result

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I have action which returns JSON

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Validate(string arg1, string arg2)
{
    bool check
    ...
    return Json(!check ? new { message = "-1" } : new { message = "1" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And I need to call that action from another action. I need that comparison for client side call (using ajax) and plus for server side validation in another post action.

How can I get message from that action?

```
var a = Validate(model.arg1, model.arg2);
a.Data;
```

returns json. How can I get value from it to compare something?

Comment: jsobject? nah I want to check if that result will equal to "-1"

Comment: Do you really need to make Validate a controller function? is it ever being accessed in `controller/action` way from the browser? if not, you could move `Validate` in another class. possible a helper.cs. reference that class and call this method from the controller you want. that should do the trick.

Comment: @MridulKashyap yeah for that I really need it.

Comment: @George for what specifically? you said it's being called from a controller action. if that's the case, it doesn't really have to be a controller functions itself. you can use it as a helper function, in another class. in fact that would be the right way to do it.

Comment: @MridulKashyap I'm doing validation from input of two textbox. Checking if private number equals to desired last name. That's from client side and doing some things using js and so on. Then I want to do that validation to back end too and don't want to duplicate code.
If there is another approach provide me some simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. create a new class file. let's say you name it `helper.cs`.

   namespace YourProject.Helper{
       public class Helper{
           // your validation code goes here.
       }
   }
2. import this class in your controller by `using YourProjectNS.Helper`

   using MyProject.Helper;
3. define the Validate function in `helper` class.

   public class Helper{
       public bool Validate(string arg1, string arg2){
           bool check
           ...
           return Json(!check ? new { message = "-1" } : new { message = "1" });
       }
   }
4. In your controller, wherever you need it, access it as `helperObj.Validate(v,v2)`

   Helper helperObj = new Helper();
   bool isValid = helperObj.Validate(v1, v2);

Ultimately your code will look something like:

in Helper.cs:

```
namespace MyProject.Helper{
    public class Helper{
        public bool Validate(string arg1, string arg2)
        {
            bool check
            ...
            return Json(!check ? new { message = "-1" } : new { message = "1" });
        }
    }
}
```

in your controller action:

```
using MyProject.Helper;

public ActionResult MyAction(){
    ...
    // your other code
    Helper helperObj = new Helper();
    bool isValid = helperObj.Validate(v1, v2);

    ...
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: why someone downvoted it? If it's bad approach provide better :)

Comment: @George The idea should be fine. The answer itself needs proper formatting and grammar. Possibly a full example piece of code since there's not much code in it.

Comment: @KevinLee would you just wait? i was doing that exactly! (-__-)

Comment: @MridulKashyap Was just explaining to George. It wasn't me who -1.

Comment: @KevinLee oh forget about that. i misread your last comment as "It was me who -1"..so..i deleted that comment when i saw it.

Comment: @MridulKashyap I deleted mine too. No problems.

Comment: @KevinLee Haha ok.